# mysql select prepared statement not sending token

Tags: php, select, prepared-statement

I have created a login system that uses a token. This prepared statement is not working. It keeps on redirecting to the error message.

I have already tried the non prepared statement here is what it looks like.

```
{
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT token FROM tbltoken WHERE token=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $token);
$token=$_POST['token'];
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($token);
if($token>0)
{
//verifying Password
if ($_POST['token']= $token) {
$_SESSION['login']=$_POST['token'];
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'dashboard.php'; </script>";
  } 
}
//if username or email not found in database
else{
echo "<script>alert('User not registered with us');</script>";
  }

}
```

The expected results of this is that the token gets sent through the statement and redirects to the page.

Comment: There are numerous problems here. Primarily that you **assign** to `$_POST['token']` with `if ($_POST['token']= $token)`. Use double (or triple) equals. Also, `$stmt->bind_result($token)` *overwrites* `$token`, so I'm not sure what you're doing with `$token=$_POST['token']` two lines prior.

Comment: You also need to call `$stmt->fetch()` after `$stmt->bind_result($token)`

Comment: Yeah still not working. Should I be writing this a different way.

Comment: yeah got it to work but thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to check for existence in the database, then you don't need to select the token. Just select 1.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare( "SELECT 1 FROM tbltoken WHERE token=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['token']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($exists);
$stmt->fetch();
if($exists) {
    //verifying Password
    $_SESSION['login']=$_POST['token'];
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'dashboard.php'; </script>";
}
//if username or email not found in database
else {
    echo "<script>alert('User not registered with us');</script>";
}
```